# How do I get min/max of id for evenly divided segments of a table which has ids which are sequential but not consecutive

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets say I have a table containing 10m rows.
I want to divide this up by 6
and then get the min and max for a column (specifically Id in this case)  for a "segment" and then represent it something like so

```
segment1 start: 1
segment1 finish:  10

segment2 start: 100001
segment2 finish: 2000000

.....
segment6 start: 9000001
segment6 end: 10000000
```

Using MSSQL.

I don't need this formatted in anyway I literally just need the numbers.

Comment: which RDBMS are you  using

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: @jarlh -  I have no query attempt.  I have an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I don't see that the segments are predefined, this could be a solution. Hope you can do something with this.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Number INT)
DECLARE @I INT
SET @I = 1

WHILE @I <= 100000
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @T VALUES(@I)
    SET @I = @I + 1
END

SELECT 'Segment: ' + CAST(Segment AS VARCHAR(5)) AS Segment, 
    MIN(Number) AS StartSegment, MAX(Number) AS EndSegment
FROM   (SELECT t.Number, NTILE(6) OVER (ORDER BY t.Number) AS Segment
        FROM @T AS t) AS a
GROUP BY a.Segment
```

Result

```
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
|Segment    |StartSegment |EndSegment |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
|Segment: 1 |1            |16667      |
|Segment: 2 |16668        |33334      |
|Segment: 3 |33335        |50001      |
|Segment: 4 |50002        |66668      |
|Segment: 5 |66669        |83334      |
|Segment: 6 |83335        |100000     |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Wow!  now looking up NTile

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH t (id) AS (
          SELECT        1
UNION ALL SELECT       10

UNION ALL SELECT   100001
UNION ALL SELECT  2000000

UNION ALL SELECT  3000000
UNION ALL SELECT  4000000

UNION ALL SELECT  5000000
UNION ALL SELECT  6000000

UNION ALL SELECT  7000000
UNION ALL SELECT  8000000

UNION ALL SELECT  9000001
UNION ALL SELECT 10000000
), rn AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) As _rn
    FROM t
), mx (         _rn,       /* number of chunks to split into */ _tgt) AS (
    SELECT MAX(_rn), CASE WHEN MAX(_rn) < 6 THEN MAX(_rn) ELSE 6 END
    FROM rn
),  s (        _i,             _from,                              _to) AS (
    SELECT      2, CAST(1 As bigint), (SELECT _rn      / _tgt FROM mx)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT _i + 1,           _to + 1, (SELECT _rn * _i / _tgt FROM mx)
    FROM s WHERE _to < (SELECT _rn FROM mx)
    )
SELECT
    _i - 1                                As [segment],
    (SELECT id FROM rn WHERE _rn = _from) As [start],
    (SELECT id FROM rn WHERE _rn = _to  ) As [finish]
FROM s
```

Using [NTile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175126.aspx) (SQL Server 2012+) following [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7703272/kevin)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42812869/5690722):

```
WITH t (id) AS (
          SELECT        1
UNION ALL SELECT       10

UNION ALL SELECT   100001
UNION ALL SELECT  2000000

UNION ALL SELECT  3000000
UNION ALL SELECT  4000000

UNION ALL SELECT  5000000
UNION ALL SELECT  6000000

UNION ALL SELECT  7000000
UNION ALL SELECT  8000000

UNION ALL SELECT  9000001
UNION ALL SELECT 10000000
), c AS (
    SELECT *, NTILE(6) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS segment
    FROM t
)
SELECT         segment,
    MIN(id) As [start],
    MAX(id) As [finish]
FROM c
GROUP BY segment
```